Is there a returning wire to the power plant/station?
In this article from this link:
https://www.energyone.com/electricity-does-not-flow-through-wires/#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20been%20led,appears%20out%20of%20thin%20air
There’s this excerpt:
“””Do the electrons flow in a loop? If you have been led to believe that the power station moves electrons toward your house on one wire and they flow through the light bulb and back to the power station on a second wire, then consider this: there is no return wire going back to the power station! There is only a single, active, wire between the power station and your house (with a break/gap at each transformer) to transmit electricity. The neutral wire that connects to your house only goes back as far as the nearest transformer in your local area or substation, where it connects to the ground (physically).“””
So is there no returning wire to the power plant? How does the power plant complete the circuit if it’s only sending wires out?

Current can only flow in a loop.

The earth can be a good conductor, given its large radius. How about we both use earth as the return path?

You are misinterpreting a rather poorly written web article.

Electric power traverses several circuits on its way from the power plant to the light bulb in your house.

From the power plant to the substation (usually 3 phases no neutral)

From the substation to the distribution transformer, typically on a pole. In the US, this is mostly 3 phases plus neutral.

From the distribution transformer to you home. In the US this is typically "split phase" plus neutral.


In each of these three circuits, current flows, well, in a circuit, i.e. a loop. Individual electrons may only move so far in one direction before the voltage reverses and they start moving in the opposite direction. But the current, flows loops, always. (Well, that actually depends on how you define "current" -- there is this thing called displacement current and if you don't take that into account, current can flow from one place to another without forming a complete loop. For example lightning. But that doesn't apply to how power gets from the power plant to your light bulb. That current, always flows in a loop.

Do the electrons flow in a loop? If you have been led to believe that the power station moves electrons toward your house on one wire and they flow through the light bulb and back to the power station on a second wire, then consider this: there is no return wire going back to the power station! There is only a single, active, wire between the power station and your house

In the US and Europe, except in very rare cases, that is not true. As @Christian B. explains in his answer, between the power plant and the substation there are generally three wires, and they "take turns" in the direction in which current is flowing. At any given moment, in at least one wire, current is flowing from the power station to the substation. In another wire, current is flowing from the substation to the power station. In the third wire, a current equal to the difference of the first two is flowing in whatever direction is required to make the algebraic total of all the currents equal to 0.
In the US, between the substation and the distribution transformer, in addition to the 3 "phase" wire, there is usually a fourth neutral wire, and some current also flows through the ground.
Also in the US, between the distribution transformer and your home, there is usually 2 live wires and a neutral.
So, at no point in this typical distribution system is current conducted only through one wire.
However, it is possible to transfer power with a single wire using the earth as a second conductor. However, in the US this is rarely the case, it is usually found only in rural areas for the private transfer of power from one point to another on private property.
Here is a live Falstad simulation of how three phase current flows between the power plant and the substation. Click on link to view.
And, here is a snapshot of that simulation.

Notice that the sum of the currents in the three lines connecting the left side to the right side is -0.001 mA. It should be \$0\$ mA exactly, however, rounding errors in the simulator cause the sum to be slightly off.

So I don’t know a lot about electricity or the power grid which is why I was so curious to ask the question. Thanks for answering btw. I learned that in the US we use 3 phase power which uses alternating current and puts power onto 3 outgoing wires. So at a given moment one of these wires can be the return path also? Each wire sort of takes its turn as the return path to the power plant/station?

I guess i just don’t understand with my very basic knowledge how the power grid using these 3 wires with alternating current complete a circuit? I think I understand how houses and substations complete a circuit but not how the power plant is part of a complete circuit? The three phase power with its alternating current really confuses me in this aspect.

Yes, the wires take turns sending current away from the power plant. However, their turns overlap a bit. Each wire sends "outgoing" current for half a cycle. But only one third of that time is that wire the only wire to send outgoing current. The other two thirds of that time, it shares the job of sending outgoing current with one or the other of the other two wires. I will see if I can create a visualization to add to my answer.

Thanks again for answering. Your response is helping me understand better. But I still don’t understand how the power plant is completing its part of the circuit. I know in a dc circuit there would have to be wires going back to the power plant to complete a loop and therefore the circuit.

In three phase distribution there are three loops defined by the three wires.  If the phases are A, B, and C, the loops are: A-B, A-C, and B-C.  The current fmwking through phase A is the sum of loops A-B and A-C.  The current flowing through phase B is the B-C minus A-B.  That's the simple explanation of circuit loop analysis: you identify the unique loops, then the current in each segment is the sum or difference of the loops it participates in.

"How does the power plant complete the circuit if it’s only sending wires out" - indicates the assumption of DC flow. Let's take a look at a fully balanced three phase power supply voltage vs phase diagram (Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3_phase_AC_waveform.svg ): 
For every phase angle you will find that the sum is always zero if all phases have the same amplitude: $$sin(x) + sin(x-\pi*1/3)+sin(x-\pi*4/3) = 0 $$
For example for 90° the full current "flows" from phase 1 into the load (transformer) and the return current is split even between phase 2 and 3.

The "Earth" is the return wire here.
Like it says towards the end of the excerpt, "The neutral wire that connects to your house only goes back as far as the nearest transformer in your local area or substation, where it connects to the ground (physically)"
This transformer in your local area or substation connects back the main power station via physical ground or "Earth".
It's the like how we used (and still use in some cases) the metal chassis of our car as a large wire. If you look at, for ex, how your horn is wired, you'll see only one red wire coming all the way from the battery. The return terminal from the horn will be just connected to the closet point in the chassis using a self tapped screw. The negative terminal of the battery will also be connected to the chassis the same way. Hence your chassis acts like a big thick wire running all around the car very conveniently.
The "Earth" in our case is the chassis.

This is not correct in the majority of industrialised countries. The transformer is either connected by three-phase connection back to the power station or, for a single phase unit, the transformer is fed from two phases of the grid. The earth connection at the transformer is to "neutralise" that line so that voltage on it remains low and fusing is not required. It also provides safety to grounded metal parts on the electrical load. AC distribution grid systems are not similar to car chassis. Metalwork and earth should not be used for return current.

Although "Single-Wire-Earth-Return" (SWER) electricity distribution systems do exist, they're the exception rather than the rule.

Usually, the high power lines coming from the power plants are 3 phase without neutral nor earth wires. At each instant, the current will flow from the wire(s) with higher potential to the wire(s) of lower potential. So there is always a way "back" for the electrons.
Why not add a neutral cable? Simply because it isn't needed as long as the phases are (approximately) balanced.
What happens at the transformer? usually the voltage is decreased (but we don't care about this for this question) and we "split" the 3 phases, so that household consumers can get just a single phase (+neutral and earth). Bigger consumers can still get all 3 phases (but usually also get the neutral). Very big consumers usually just get the 3 phases without neutral, and are responsible to keep the phases balanced.
NB : in some really remote areas, there are power lines with a single wire, using earth as return : it's less efficient and less stable, but it's the cheapest solution for very remote areas.
